# Storing and retrieving objects in javascript array();

Tags: javascript

Hi I've searched for the answer but since the tutorials online are all `friends = ("bob","fred","joe");` I dont get anywhere. I would like to be able to store several objects with 1-3 values in each index of the array like:

`map = [{ground:0},{ground:0, wall:1},{ground:0, item:3}]`

The object I have right now looks like:

```
node = {};
node = {ground:0, object:1};
```

But when I try the array way I can't access it, all I get "object Object". What would be the correct way to get the values from the map array one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, or what you mean by "the array way", but if you want to get all the values for say *ground*, then:

```
var map = [{ground:0},{ground:0, wall:1},{ground:0, item:3}]

for (var i=0, iLen=map.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  alert(map[i].ground);
}
```

#### Edit

```
...
  alert('item ' + i + ' : ' + map[i].ground); // item 0 : 0
...
```

Comment: While I'm at it, how do I alert the number of the map[i], so i get say map[0] etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
var map = [{ground:0},{ground:0, wall:1},{ground:0, item:3}];
for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    console.log(map[i].ground + " item " + map[i].item);
}
```